# Python Crash Course - Ch. 7, Exercise 5

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working through the Python Crash Course book. I'm stuck on Chapter 7 (User Input and While Loops), Exercise 5 (Movie Tickets). Problem statement: A movie theater charges different ticket prices depending on a person’s age. If a person is under the age of 3, the ticket is free; if they are between 3 and 12, the ticket is $10; and if they are over age 12, the ticket is $15. Write a loop in which you ask users their age, and then tell them the cost of their movie ticket.

My code is almost identical to the posted solution, with one change: the position of the part of the code that reads

```py
age = input(prompt)
```

which changes how the code works, and I'm unsure of why. Specifically: with my code, the print statements run forever (e.g. it'll print "Your ticket is $15" without end in Terminal when I try and run the program). Both solutions posted below (mine first, textbook's second).

My code:

```py
prompt = "How old are you?"
prompt += "\nEnter 'quit' when finished. "

age = input(prompt) 

while True:
    if age == 'quit':
        break
    age = int(age)

    if age < 3:
        print(" You get in free!")
    elif 3 < age < 12:
        print(" Your ticket is $10.")
    else:
        print("Your ticket is $15.")
```

Textbook solution:

```py
prompt = "How old are you?"
prompt += "\nEnter 'quit' when you are finished. "

while True:
    age = input(prompt)
    if age == 'quit':
        break
    age = int(age)

    if age < 3:
        print("  You get in free!")
    elif age < 13:
        print("  Your ticket is $10.")
    else:
        print("  Your ticket is $15.")
```

Is anyone able to explain the logic behind this? Thanks.

Comment: Think about how many times `age = input()` is run when it's inside the loop, and how many times it's run when it's outside of the loop. How many times does `prompt` print out for each?

Comment: Their code includes the prompt within the loop, which is a blocking operation..

Comment: Per my understanding:
 - When inside the loop, age = input() automatically runs and prints the prompt right after the output is printed, each time the output is printed.
- When outside the loop, age = input() runs once, allowing the user only one chance to provide an age, which the program then prints again and again. 

I'm confused re: how/why the program returns to printing the prompt in the textbook example, but prints the output infinitely in my example. After all, there's nothing in the if/elif/else statements requiring it to reprint the prompt in the textbook's example.

Comment: @Anirudh did you read my comment? the `input` prompt blocks the loop until user-input has been entered. You can also repeat this this over and over within the loop, but if the prompt resides outside the loop, then it will repeat automatically...

Comment: @Anirudh Your version prints infinitely because the loop can only exit if `age` is `"quit"`, and you only ask for age once before entering the loop. If age wasn't "quit" when the loop was entered, it will never be "quit" since you never ask for the age again. It works in the textbook example because age is asked for once per loop, so the user can change age every time the program loops.

Comment: Regarding "there's nothing . . . requiring it to reprint the prompt in the textbook example". Yes there is: `age = input(prompt)`.

Comment: @BlueRineS - just saw that sorry - I get it now, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Thanks @Carcigenicate - I'm super new so anything that's not an explicit 'print' is evidently over my head lol.

Comment: @Anirudh The argument passed to `input` (`prompt`) is printed automatically. It would be the same as if you had wrote `print(prompt, end=""); age = input()`. The `end=""` is to stop print from adding a newline at the end.

Comment: Also, be careful when `age=3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first example you will have the input for the age asked only once (before the loop starts) and then the start of the loop which checks if the `age` variable is `quit`, so if you insert `3` as the input it will never change to `quit` and you have an infinite loop.

On the second example (from the textbook) you will be asked to input again the age, so here the user has the option of changing the variable `age` to `quit` or just another integer value. Changing it to `quit` makes the execution of the `while True:` be broken and the code gracefully stops.

As mentioned by Michael on another answer you should use `age.lowercase()` to guarantee the loop to break if the input is `QUIT` or `Quit`, for example. Also it would be nice to validate if the input is an integer before running `int(age)` because `int('3.14')` or `int('foo'`) will get you an error.

For checking if a string could be represented as a valid positive integer you could use this:

```py
str = '10'
is_valid = str.isdigit()
```

In this case `is_valid` is a boolean storing if it is valid or not.

Answer (score 0):

Because the call to input() is not in the loop body, it will only ever be run once. When the loop repeats, it jumps to the 'while True:', not the entire script again.

As a side note, you may also want to ensure/protect against your input being type String, but not equal to 'quit', and call 'quit'.tolower() to ensure uppercase characters are also caught :)

Comment: Thanks Michael. Made the change. 

To clarify: the loop repeats simply because that's the nature of while loops as long as while == True, correct?

Comment: @Anirudh `while` is not a boolean, as long as the statemetn after `while` is equal to `True` to be more precise, it will keep running.

Comment: Yes that is correct. You would see the same behaviour if the 'True' was a variable set to True, and instead of calling 'break' you set this variable to False, as the evaluation of the loop control variable would no longer be True.